# Can I add boostrap panel within bootsrap rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap on a page with a long list of inputs. To center it on the page I'm using the following column layout (also using ejs/javascript):

```
<%  
    var col1 = 'col-md-2';  //space left 
    var col2 = 'col-md-3';  //label 
    var col3 = 'col-md-4';  //input 
    var col4 = 'col-md-4';  //space right 
%>
```

To add some sort of order to the inputs and separate option controls I'm grouping them with the panel class, so something like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='<%= col1 %>'></div>
        <div class='<%= col2 %>'>First Name</div>
        <div class='<%= col3 %>'>
            <input type='text'  name='_firstname' value='' /> 
        </div>
        <div class='<%= col4 %>'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='<%= col1 %>'></div>
        <div class='<%= col2 %>'>Last Name</div>
        <div class='<%= col3 %>'>
            <input type='text'  name='_lastname' value='' /> 
        </div>
        <div class='<%= col4 %>'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Logically the lines for the panel wraps around col1-col4. But is there anyway I can cut the outside out and just apply the box around col2-col3, without messing up all the nice bootstrap resizing features?

I don't see how it can be done using straight bootstrap, but I'm not ver adept with css so wanted to check on here and/or see if anyone had any other ideas how I could tackle this.

Comment: Do you mean you would like to reserve the left and right spacing without using `col1` and `col4`?

Comment: Yes I want to keep the label and input centered more in the middle of the screen, with a grouping box just around those. I could just drop the bootstrap columns and do some straight CSS, to get that effect, but I'm trying to maintain the nice resizing features bootstrap provides.

Comment: You can consider to enable the flex behaviors by using the class `d-flex justify-content-center`. http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: Actually sorry I didn't properly comprehend you're first question, I don't need to reserve that space for anything rather it's purely for alignment. Seems to me like I'll run into the same issue with the flexbox, but maybe I can work something using the border controls.

Comment: It would be great if you can add the design draft in the question.